# Can't run python script converted to exe

Tags: python, exe, executable, py2exe, cx-freeze

I have created a python program that sends data to google spreadsheets using the following external libaries:

- json
- gspread
- oauth2client

The program works as expected, however when I tried to convert it to an executable, I would get the following error every time I rune the .exe file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
exec(code, m.__dict__)
File "Demo.py", line 13, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\util.py", line 140, in positional_wrapper
return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1630, in __init__
_RequireCryptoOrDie()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\client.py", line 1581, in _RequireCryptoOrDie
raise CryptoUnavailableError('No crypto library available')
oauth2client.client.CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available
```

Would any of you guys know what the problem could be, and what steps I could take to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Edit: I tried to use both cx_freeze and py2exe. I got similar errors in both

Below is the setup.py I used in cx_freeze:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name = "Demo" ,
  version = "1.0" ,
  description = "A python Demo" ,
  executables = [Executable("Demo.py")])
```

Comment: Are you using py2exe, or cx-freeze?  Seeing your setup files would help.  Do you have pycrypto installed?

Comment: PyInstaller works best in my experience. Sometimes you have to declare modules to be packed together into a binary though (it's not always smart enough to figure out all the necessary imports).