# My python exe will not run 2 other python exe's

Tags: python-3.x

Edit: This was fixed!

I show my friends most of the python programs I make, and I sometimes make small programs for them (on commission). I made a program that runs `MS Paint` and writes some words that may or may not be ok to say here (It is high school).

To do this, I used pyautogui (Freakin' wonderful module btw). I used a file called RunMe to run two separate files. One opens Paint, the other draws the words.

The friend I was making this for did not want to install `python` on his computer, so I compiled the files (Thinking that would make them work). They did not work on his computer, so I tried to make them .exe's.

The python files work as normal .py and as .pyc files, but when I converted them to .exe, they did not work.

The closest thing I could find, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185411/cant-run-python-script-converted-to-exe), is not the same thing, as I can run the file, but it will not run the other 2.

Here is the code for the files:

**RunMe.exe** (*This one runs the files*):

```
from threading import Thread

def one(): import openpaint.exe
def two(): import drawmychilddraw.exe

Thread(target=one).start()
Thread(target=two).start()
```

**DrawMyChildDraw.exe** (*this one is for drawing the letters*):

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time as t
import math as m

pg.moveTo(400, 450, 0.1)

## this is a U

pg.drag(0, 200, 0.1)

pg.drag(50, 0 , 0.1)

pg.drag(0, -200, 0.1)

pg.moveRel(100, 200, 0.1)

## This is an H

pg.drag(0, -200, 0.1)

pg.moveRel(0, 100, 0.1)

pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)

pg.moveRel(0, 100, 0.1)

pg.drag(0, -200, 0.1)

## this is an O

pg.moveRel(0, 100, 0.1)

pg.moveRel(50, 0, 0.1)

pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)

pg.drag(0, 100, 0.1)

pg.drag(-50, 0, 0.1)

pg.drag(0, -100, 0.1)

## this is an E

pg.moveRel(100, 0, 0.1)

pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)

pg.drag(0, 50, 0.1)

pg.drag(-50, 0, 0.1)

pg.drag(0, -50, 0.1)

pg.drag(0, 100, 0.1)

pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)

## this is a !

pg.moveRel(100, 0, 0.1)

pg.drag(0, -25, 0.1)

pg.moveRel(0, -25, 0.1)

pg.drag(0, -150, 0.1)

pg.moveRel(0, 200, 0.1)
```

**RunPaint.exe** (*this on runs MS Paint*):

```
import os
os.system('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe')
```

If anyone knows what might cause this, or how to fix it, it would be very awesome. Thanks!

Edit: This was fixed!

Comment: Why not make your three scripts into one script??

Comment: _"They did not work on his computer"_ I guess you should solve that problem first. What makes you think that compiling them into .exe will make them work?

Comment: @Reedinationer I tried that to start, but I ended up with lots of problems that the three script solution fixed.

Comment: @Selcuk That was because they were in python form and he did not have python installed. His computer is running the same OS as me, and has slightly better specs. The whole point of using .exe's was to try to fix the issue, however, when I tested it on my computer, the .exe's did not work, so I came here to ask about why that might be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to simplify your code into a single script:

```
from threading import Thread
import pyautogui as pg
import os
import time


def main():
    t = Thread(target=open_paint)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    draw_uhoe()


def open_paint():
    os.system('C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mspaint.exe')


def draw_uhoe():
    print('drawing')
    pg.moveTo(400, 450, 0.1)

    # this is a U

    pg.drag(0, 200, 0.1)
    pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, -200, 0.1)
    pg.moveRel(100, 200, 0.1)

    # This is an H

    pg.drag(0, -200, 0.1)
    pg.moveRel(0, 100, 0.1)
    pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)
    pg.moveRel(0, 100, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, -200, 0.1)

    # this is an O

    pg.moveRel(0, 100, 0.1)
    pg.moveRel(50, 0, 0.1)
    pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, 100, 0.1)
    pg.drag(-50, 0, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, -100, 0.1)

    # this is an E

    pg.moveRel(100, 0, 0.1)
    pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, 50, 0.1)
    pg.drag(-50, 0, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, -50, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, 100, 0.1)
    pg.drag(50, 0, 0.1)

    # this is a !
    pg.moveRel(100, 0, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, -25, 0.1)
    pg.moveRel(0, -25, 0.1)
    pg.drag(0, -150, 0.1)
    pg.moveRel(0, 200, 0.1)

main()
```

Having a single script is just easier in my opinion, but not entirely necessary. 
Once you have this made, make another python file in the same directory called `setup.py`:

**setup.py**

```
import sys
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
additional_modules = []

build_exe_options = {"includes": additional_modules,
                     "packages": ["threading", "pyautogui", "os", "time"],
                     "excludes": [],
                     "include_files": [
                                       os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
                                       os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll')
                                       ]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(name="LetterDrawer",
      version="1.0",
      description="U hoe!",
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=[Executable("workspace.py", base=base)]) #change workspace.py to your file name
```

Now open a terminal in that folder and run `python setup.py build`. This will create an executable for you in a new directory called `build`. (You may have to run the command twice). Now open that folder and run the .exe to check it worked. If it did you have to send your friend the **whole** folder with the .exe (including all the .dlls). This will allow them to run the program without python installed (hence all the dlls). On my machine doing this with the provided code created an executable that accomplished the desired task. Let me know if you have questions on something I was unclear about, but otherwise if this fixed your problem I'd appreciate if you click that check mark by my post to accept it as the solution

Comment: When I tried to install cx_Freeze it "failed to build a wheel". I tried to install it twice and both times this happened. If you know why this could be, and you could tell me, when you have the time, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, It was a issue with my version of python.

Comment: Thanks for this solution btw. I've prolly come back here like 10 times to use the py -> exe code lmao